# Is there a way to trigger a pyshell glue job after successfully running three pyspark glue job?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue

There are three pyspark glue jobs, Job1, Job2 and Job3 and one pyshell job Job4
Job1 runs at 8 am
Job2 runs at 9 am
Job3 runs at 10 am

These jobs are independent of each other

Once these jobs are ran successfully I need to run Job4
Job4 should not run if any of these jobs failed

How can I achieve this without using lambda or Step functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Glue is coming with its own workflow capability.

It will cover nicely your scheduled trigger, conditional transition, mix of pyspark and pyshell jobs.

Check
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/workflows_overview.html